# Why is $_GET set by default?

Tags: php

I've searched for a while but couldn't find an answer

```
if(isset($_GET)) {
    # return true
}
```

Why does the above return true even when the script has no URL parameters?

The URL of the script is domain.com/script.php with nothing appended at the end. Why does this return true?

Comment: because this is how php works, global variable is set and initialized as empty array

Comment: thanks, I'll keep in mind in the future

Answer (score 5):

Because the [superglobals are always present](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). Use `if (!empty($_GET))` to check if it actually contains values.

> By default, all of the superglobals are available but there are directives that affect this availability. For further information, refer to the documentation for `variables_order`.

Comment: Should be !empty,  empty() would be checking if it doesn't have values.  You could also use `if count($_GET)` since it is an array, if it returns > 0 it will be evaluated true.

Comment: if ($_GET) should work.  http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php is a good table to show it.  You could always test this yourself too, since $_GET is an empty array `[] == true // returns false`